# Equivalent of SQL Server trace for Oracle 10g?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, trace

I've got a bad code duplication problem where we cannot tell which versions of packages/procedures are being used.  i.e. I have different packages with procedures of the same name and I need to be sure which packages are not actually being called.

I'm trying to eliminate procedures/packages of the same name which are no longer being called.  I'd like to run the trace for a few weeks, combine the data and query the metadata against it and find candidates for further investigation and deactivation.